# Download and reuse Amazon public datasets on multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running in us-east-1 that needs to be able to access/manipulate data available in the [KITTI Vision Benchmark public dataset](https://registry.opendata.aws/kitti/). I'd like to make this data available to the instance, but would also like to be able to reuse it with other instances in the future (more like a mounted S3 approach).

Other similar questions get at downloading from the bucket directly... and I understand that I can view the bucket and recursively download the data to a local folder using AWS cli from within the instance:

`aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://avg-kitti/`

`aws s3 sync s3://avg-kitti/` or `aws s3 cp s3://avg-kitti/ . --recursive`

However, this feels like a brute force approach and would likely require me to increase my EBS volume size... and would limit my reuse of this data elsewhere (unless I was to snapshot and reuse the entire EBS volume). I did find some stackoverflow solutions that mentioned some of the open data sets being available as [a snapshot you could copy over and attach as a volume](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12699/how-can-i-download-aws-public-datasets). But the [KITTI Vision Benchmark public dataset](https://registry.opendata.aws/kitti/) appears to be on S3 so I don't think it would have a snapshot like it would on EBS datasets...

That being said, is there an easier way to copy public data over to an existing S3 bucket? and then mount my instance to that? I have played around with S3FS and feel like that might be my best bet, but I am worried about 1) the cost of copying / downloading all data from public bucket to my own 2) best approach for reusing this data on other instances 3) simply not knowing if there's a better/cheaper way to make this data available without downloading or needing to download again in the future.

Comment: Do you really need to download everything at once? how big is the bucket?

Comment: There are various tools for 'mounting' S3 on computers. I wonder whether you could mount the `avg-kitti` bucket directly? (Possibly not, since it isn't your bucket and therefore won't allow Writes.) Yes, you could use `aws s3 sync` to copy the data to your own bucket with: `aws s3 sync s3://avg-kitti/ s3://your-bucket-here/`

Comment: @Marcin - The bucket is over 100GB and that's with most of the files/folders zipped.. I guess there are specific things I could be targeted about downloading.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I've played with S3FS and it might be the best route here, but was still hoping to get around downloading all the public data to a newly created bucket I mount to. You are kinda poking at what I was wondering - if there was a way to mount or clone the bucket directly (without having to download it in it's entirety)